# Using custom machine learning models in Flutter

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, firebase-mlkit

**Objective -**
I am working on a movie recommendation mobile application in Flutter which will ask for the user's favourite movie and will then recommend a bunch of other similar movies using machine learning model.

**Problem -**
The Flutter application is ready, the model to recommend movies is also ready but the only problem here is the deployment of the model i.e how am I supposed to use my model with my Flutter application.

**My Solution -**
I have figured out two methods -

***The one which is working*** -

Either creating and hosting a Web API Service (say using flask) and calling the API Service from my Flutter application to fetch the result.

***The one which is not working*** -

But on the other way if I use the Firebase Ml Kit there are few pre-defined ready to use models also there is one option to upload your own custom model but I could not find any informative material regarding how to use my own custom model with flutter. The examples and the videos which I have referred were using custom models but for Image Processing and Text Recognition etc. It will be a great help if anybody can throw some light on how to use your own model with flutter.

*For Example, If I want to use the below model with flutter what will be the procedure for that..*

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1,input_shape =[1])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
          loss='mean_squared_error',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
xs = np.array([-1.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0])
ys = np.array([-3.0,-1.0,0.0,3.0,5.0,7.0])
model.fit(xs,ys,epochs=500)
print(model.predict([10.0]))
keras_file = "test.tf"
keras.models.save_model(model,keras_file)
```

Comment: Hi, Akhil Shukla, were you able to implement the model in flutter

Comment: Hi Sravan , No I wasn't able to accomplish that using Flutter ML library but rather created a flask API and hosted my model into it and finally used Http library in flutter to call the API.

Comment: Akhil Shukla, I was able to implement the model in firebase. All, we need is tflite model. this is my github link. - https://github.com/SravanKumar35/Flutter-ML-Model-Integration

Comment: Thanks a lot Sravan for your help. I will refer from your repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [firebase_ml_custom](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_custom) plugin to manage hosting the model and downloading it to user's device.

Comment: Are you still using this package? How did you get past the outdated firebase dependencies?